# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'void akka.actor.ExtensionId.$init$(akka.actor.ExtensionId)'

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream, akka-http, scala-3

I am simply trying to implement a little sample REST endpoint in a scala project using akka.
The code looks as follows

```
import akka.http.scaladsl.Http
import akka.http.scaladsl.model.{ContentTypes, HttpEntity}

import akka.actor.typed.ActorSystem
import akka.actor.typed.scaladsl.Behaviors
import scala.io.StdIn

import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContextExecutor


object ViewAPI :
  @main def run(): Unit = {
    implicit val system = ActorSystem(Behaviors.empty, "my-system")
    implicit val executionContext = system.executionContext
    val route =
      path("hello") {
        get {
          complete(HttpEntity(ContentTypes.`text/html(UTF-8)`, "<h1>Say hello to akka-http</h1>"))
        }
      }
    val bindingFuture = Http().newServerAt("localhost", 9001).bind(route)

  }
```

My sbt-file looks as follows:

```
libraryDependencies += ("com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-http" % "10.2.9").cross(CrossVersion.for3Use2_13)

libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-actor-typed" % "2.6.19"

libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-stream" % "2.6.19"

libraryDependencies += "org.scalactic" %% "scalactic" % "3.2.11"

libraryDependencies += "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "3.2.12-RC1" % "test"

libraryDependencies += "org.scala-lang.modules" %% "scala-swing" % "3.0.0"

libraryDependencies += "com.google.inject" % "guice" % "4.2.3"

libraryDependencies += ("net.codingwell" %% "scala-guice" % "5.0.2").cross(CrossVersion.for3Use2_13)

libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-json" % "2.10.0-RC5"

libraryDependencies += "org.scala-lang.modules" %% "scala-xml" % "2.0.1"

resolvers += Resolver.url("scoverage-bintray", url("https://dl.bintray.com/sksamuel/sbt-plugins/"))(Resolver.ivyStylePatterns)
```

And these are the libraries in the project

```
sbt: com.typesafe.akka:akka-actor-typed_3:2.6.19:jar
sbt: com.typesafe.akka:akka-actor_3:2.6.19:jar
sbt: com.typesafe.akka:akka-http-core_2.13:10.2.9:jar
sbt: com.typesafe.akka:akka-http_2.13:10.2.9:jar
sbt: com.typesafe.akka:akka-parsing_2.13:10.2.9:jar
sbt: com.typesafe.akka:akka-protobuf-v3_3:2.6.19:jar
sbt: com.typesafe.akka:akka-slf4j_3:2.6.19:jar
sbt: com.typesafe.akka:akka-stream_3:2.6.19:jar
```

When trying to execute the above code, the following exception is thrown:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'void akka.actor.ExtensionId.$init$(akka.actor.ExtensionId)'
    at akka.http.scaladsl.Http$.<clinit>(Http.scala:845)
    at caro.aview.ViewAPI$.run(ViewAPI.scala:23)
    at caro.aview.run.main(ViewAPI.scala:14)
```

Does anybody have an idea why that is? Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Dependency conflict with libraries requiring/pulling incompatible versions of akka-actor, check `dependencyTree`

Comment: Very strange. This code work fine on Scala 2.13.8 by the way, but don't work on Scala 3

Comment: @MikhailIonkin Yeah, it works when using 2.13 for all akka libraries, as the top answer said, must be a bug in scala 3

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I also have this problem. The solution was moving all akka libraries back to Scala 2.13 using the CrossVersion.for3Use2_13 option, the same you have used for akka-http. Looks like a bug in akka for scala 3 version.

Answer (score 0):

In my project I was getting the same error. I was using 2.13 scala version for one akka package and 3 scala version for another akka package in the pom.xml. Changed both to use 3 and it fixed the error.